# If you had to make an exclusively masculine noun refer to something feminine, would you just change the ending?

Tags: grammar-choice, gender

*Sagittarius* ("archer"), as a noun, is exclusively masculine, but I am trying to refer to a female archer in Latin. Would simply changing the ending to *sagittaria* suffice?

Comment: At a glance, I'd say the answer is yes, but the question in the title seems to ask something different.

Comment: In the case of *sagittarius, -ii,* that's just an adjective used substantively; i.e., *sagitta, -ae* 'arrow' -> *sagittarius, -ia, -ium* 'pertaining to arrows' -> *sagittarius, -ii* 'man who shoots arrows, archer'. *Sagittaria, -iae* would be the natural choice for 'woman who shoots arrows'.

Comment: Related: [Is the phrase professor emerita grammatically correct?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/7516), [Can masculine 1st-decl. nouns be feminine? (e.g. “Nauta perita”?)](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/379)

Answer (score 3):

In this particular case, yes. *Sagittārius* is the masculine form of an adjective meaning "pertaining to arrows"; the feminine form would be *sagittāria*.

In general…it depends. Many masculine Latin words are in the second declension, and these can be made feminine by changing the ending to *-a*. Many others can be treated as "common gender", used as masculine or feminine with no change (e.g. a *poeta* can be a poet of either sex).

As a rule of thumb, if it ends in *-us*, change it to *-a*, otherwise don't change anything. This isn't perfect and will sometimes fail, but 90% of the time it'll get you the right answer.