# Translation of a sentence by Darwin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

> Multiply, vary, let the strongest live and the weakest die.
> -- Charles Darwin

I translated this sentence by:

> Crescite, mutate, fortissima vivite, alia morimini.
> -- Carolus Darwin

However, I am not sure if I can use *fortissima* and *alia* as nouns. Conjugation should be correct if verbs are indeed at the imperative form.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're correct that the imperative is the best option for the first two verbs. The second two verbs, though, would be excellent candidates for a [hortatory subjunctive](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/hortatory-subjunctive). It's also completely permissible to use an adjective as a noun--the only difference is that I would use the masculine, since Darwin's law is about animals, not things.

Here's how I would translate the whole thing:

> **Multiplicamini, variate, vivant validissimi, et moriantur infirmissimi.**

I use *multiplicamini* because this seems to be an echo of [Genesis 1:22](https://www.sacred-texts.com/bib/vul/gen001.htm): you'll notice that most of the examples in the [Lewis & Short entry](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dmultiplico) use the passive for this sense of "be increased."

I also chose *vario* (instead of *muto*) because the idea is not only to *change*, but to *change in different ways*. *Vario* is a common word that is mostly synonymous to the English cognate Darwin uses, "vary."

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and for having made me discover the hortatory subjunctive. I used mutor because according to the Olivetti dictionary, vario is a transitive verb. I could also use alii instead of infirmissimi so that the quote covers all beings. And finally, does the masculine also apply to plants? Thanks again!

Comment: One difference between Blincer's original translation and this one is that he added the audience: "you, the strongest [beings], must live, while you, the other [beings], must perish". I suppose either is possible, depending on the desired effect. But you are of course right that the original is also in the third person. // As to the gender, the noun *animal* is neuter.

Comment: @Cerberus *animal* is neuter, but I think a masculine plural would still be plural given that [pretty much every single animal name is masculine or feminine](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/13994/is-any-animal-neuter-in-latin). A neuter plural adjective strongly suggests to my ear "things that are *X*" to the exclusion of people and animals. But I could be wrong!

Comment: @Blincer According to Lewis & Short *vario* can also be used intransitively. "Alii" would be fine, though (obviously) it's a bit different from what Darwin says. As for plants, I suspect that masculine wouldn't be appropriate in that case.