# What trustworthy books in French introduce Latin?

Tags: resource-request, study-strategies

To wit, I'm seeking a French equivalent of [*Wheelock's Latin*](https://redd.it/4dzybs).

I'm not asking about [natural approaches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_approach) like [*Lingua Latina*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_%C3%98rberg).

Answer (score 2):

I have used "Cornélie, ou le latin sans pleurs", by Salomon Reinach (1912), and liked it.  This may be older than you were looking for.  But if I remember Wheelock rightly, I think Reinach has a similar jaunty, chatty tone and an emphasis on reading short, typically edifying, passages.  It's available online through the [Bibliothèque nationale de France](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k2053962.image).

He wrote a similar book for Greek - "Eulalie, ou le grec sans larmes" (1911) - also available via the BnF site.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say whether it's trustworthy or not, and it is quite old, but one French book that aims to introduce its reader to Latin is *Nouvelle Méthode Pour Apprendre Facilement La Langue Latine: Contenant Les Regles Des Genres, Des Déclinaisons, Des Préterits, de la Syntaxe, de la Quantité, & des Accens Latins, mises en françois avec un ordre très-clair & très-abregé.* You can view the [1761 edition](https://books.google.com/books?id=22MSAAAAIAAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) for free via Google Books.

I found it of use when I was looking for information about [the declension of the noun *Pascha*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/10678/9).